# How to get highlighted (selected) mail from outlook using Python?

Tags: python, outlook, ms-office

I can not understand how to parse highlighted (selected) mail from outlook using Python?

I have this code, but it works with last mail.

```
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)

messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetLast()
body_content = message.body
print (body_content)
```

Need to parse sender email address of highlighted mail?

Comment: Your question is at certain points vague.... for example what do you mean with "last mail"? Add versions of python, outlook and OS you're using. And above all.. finish the tour and you understand how to improve your question. End of triage review --> requires editing.

Answer (score 1):

*Should be*

```
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
messages = outlook.ActiveExplorer().Selection
message = messages(1)

try:
    if message.SenderEmailType == "EX":
        print("EX: ", message.Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress)
    else:
        if message.SenderEmailType == "SMTP":
            print("SMTP: ", message.SenderEmailAddress)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)` to retrieve the currently selected message. Your code retrieves the last email in the Inbox - whatever "last" is, since you never explicitly sort the items collection. Most likely you will end up with the oldest email in the Inbox.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. Can you please help me with this case? How to correctly write this code?

Comment: What is it exactly that you are having problems with?

Comment: Outlook does not know or care whether it is being invoked by Python or VB.